# Android Studio Windows 8.1 Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am running Android Studio on Windows 8.1.  When I try to run simple Hello World on a virtual device, it shows briefly then exits with dialog "The emulator process for AVD [device] has terminated.

Here is the output from the `idea.log`:

```
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_22 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | encryption is off 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release. 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only. 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | added library C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\lib64\vulkan\vulkan-1.dll 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. 
INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\[my_username]\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_1072.ini 
INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 state changed to ONLINE 
INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 state changed to OFFLINE 
WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.8.0 (build_id 8143646) (CL:N/A) 
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) 
WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819 
INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected
```

However, I am able to run it from the command line successfully.  The log is nearly identical:

[image: command line emulator]

I have searched these forums and tried everything:

- Change Graphics Performance option to "Software"
- Cold Boot Now option
- Wipe Data option
- Delete `.android` folder
- Delete, create multiple different virtual devices
- Run as Administrator
- Install, reinstall Android Emulator
- Increase IDE memory to max (2GB)
- Reboot machine

I am out of ideas.  Has anyone been able to solve this?

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 16, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.60 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 8.1 6.3
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore (4.1.0), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```